# Overloading a method in com visible dll

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript, overloading

I am creating a COM visible dll and I was trying to overload a method.

So basically this code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("TAF.TextLog")]
[Guid("af3f89ed-4732-4367-a222-2a95b8b75659")]
public class TextLog
{
    String _logFilePath;

    public TextLog()
    {
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Create(string filePath)
    {
        String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            _logFilePath = filePath;
        }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        WriteMessage(null, message, AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Info);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void Write(string title, string message, AlertMsg.MsgTypes messageType)
    {
        WriteMessage(title, message, messageType);
    }

    private void WriteMessage(string title, string message, AlertMsg.MsgTypes messageType)
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(_logFilePath, true))
        {
            if (title == null)
                file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\t{1}", DateTime.Now, message));
            else
                file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", DateTime.Now, title, message, messageType));
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this is not possible however. If I call .Write from the calling program (which is a very simple VBSCript by the way), i get an error that my parameters are not correct.

This is the calling VBscript code:

```
Set myObj = CreateObject("TAF.TextLog")
myObj.Create("C:\temp\textlog.txt")
myObj.Write "title", "test message 1", 1
```

If I have only one .Write method in the dll it works fine. Can someone tell me if overloading like this is even possible in a dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM does not have support for member overloads, each name *must* be unique.  An inevitable side-effect of [IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The function that the script interpreter uses to translate "Write" as used in the scripting code to a dispid.  The method still exists, there's just no way to get GetIDsOfNames() to return its dispid.  The type library exporter solves this problem by *renaming* the overloaded method, it will be `Write_2()`.

No workaround for that when you use late-binding afaik, you must avoid overloads.

Answer (score 0):

COM doesn't really support overloading.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182197(v=vs.80).aspx