# Which method overload will be accessible from VBScript?

Tags: c#, vbscript, overloading

`System.Collections.ArrayList` is `ComVisible(true)`. It contains three overloads of `IndexOf` (see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,9a21eb977feec66d)):

```cs
public virtual int IndexOf(Object value)
public virtual int IndexOf(Object value, int startIndex)
public virtual int IndexOf(Object value, int startIndex, int count)
```

From VBScript, only the second overload can be accessed:

```vb
Dim oList
Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'oList.IndexOf "foo"        'Error: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'IndexOf'
 oList.IndexOf "foo", 0
'oList.IndexOf "foo", 0, 1  'Error: Wrong number of arguments or property assignment was not valid: 'IndexOf'
```

In ['Overloading a method in com visible dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650296/1671066) Hans Passant explains that
overload methods exist in the assembly, but from script one cannot get their
dispid and therefore call them. This seems to imply that one method might make it through though.

- Can I determine from the ArrayList source (or elsewhere), which method will be accessible? What are the rules, that govern this selection process?
- Why are the error messages different for case one and three?

Comment: As is stated [here(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182197.aspx), _When overloaded methods are exposed to COM clients, only the first method overload retains its name_ . I don't know why this is not the case,unless the code provided in your link is not accurate...

Comment: Like @Pikoh say's only the first overload retains the name *(also Hans points this out - "The type library exporter solves this problem by renaming the overloaded method, it will be `Write_2()`.")* why you not trying `oList.IndexOf_2 "foo", 0` and `oList.IndexOf_3 "foo", 0, 1`?

Comment: In fact all methods are exposed. For example, you can access the one parameter override with :`oList.IndexOf_3 "foo"` or the 3 parameters as `oList.IndexOf_2 "foo", 0, 1`

Comment: @Pikoh It's just working out in which order the overloads are exposed when the Type Exporter renames them `IndexOf()`, `IndexOf_2()` and `IndexOf_3()` which isn't hard. Fairly confident [Hans already covers this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25650296/692942) in the other question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good find, also confirms order is based off original order they are defined in the assembly.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart that wasn't easy to find, needed bunch of key words.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, didn't come up on my radar. Still think Hans explanation of the behaviour is a bit more concise.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Another dup [Overloads in COM interop (CCW) - IDispatch names include suffix (_2, _3, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1277740/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart yeah, not sure which to close now... maybe better leave it like that. (i.e. close this one as dupe of what I found, leaving the other one as-is)

Comment: @micha You've been very quiet, did any of the suggestions help?

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you, I have thinking about it. It turns out, that my question was a bad question, because it based on a wrong assumption. Nevertheless the answers have been helpful and seem useful in general. Since this is a chatty comment to update you, I will delete it in 24 h to clean up the comments for other viewers. Thank you for being so supportive.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I wouldn't worry about that and you're welcome. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: All of them.

---

Let's analyse what [@hans-passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) has written;

> <sup>[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650296/692942) to [Overloading a method in com visible dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25650039/692942)</sup>
> *COM does not have support for member overloads, each name must be unique. An inevitable side-effect of [`IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The function that the script interpreter uses to translate "Write" as used in the scripting code to a dispid. The method still exists, there's just no way to get `GetIDsOfNames()` to return its dispid. **The type library exporter solves this problem by renaming the overloaded method, it will be `Write_2()`**.*

It's in two parts

1. Explaining the behaviour of `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()`
2. How the Type Library Exporter solves uniqueness issue.

It doesn't say they are not available, on the contrary they have been renamed to avoid the uniqueness constraint that `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames()` has when assigning `DISPID` to the method name.

So all three overloads are available just renamed using the following format

```
oList.IndexOf
oList.IndexOf_2
oList.IndexOf_3
```

> <sup>**Note:** There is no `IndexOf_1` because the first overload always takes the original method name and subsequent overloads start from `_2` onwards.</sup>

Depending on how the Type Library Exporter renames the overloads will depend which one takes which set of arguments, the only way to work this out is trial and error.

Quick attempt at a test

```vb
Dim oList
Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

oList.Add "bar"
oList.Add "foo"

WScript.Echo oList.IndexOf("foo", 0)
WScript.Echo oList.IndexOf_2("foo", 0, 1)
WScript.Echo oList.IndexOf_3("foo")
```

Output:

```
1
-1
1
```

---

#### Why do the two statements fail with different errors?

If we go back to your original example

```vb
Dim oList
Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'oList.IndexOf "foo"        'Error: Invalid procedure call or argument: 'IndexOf'
 oList.IndexOf "foo", 0
'oList.IndexOf "foo", 0, 1  'Error: Wrong number of arguments or property assignment was not valid: 'IndexOf'
```

Statement one and three fail with different errors due to how VBScript evaluates the method signatures. The correct signature in the above example accepts two arguments so the first statement;

```vb
oList.IndexOf "foo"
```

will fail because the only matching signature has two arguments not one hence the error;

> Invalid procedure call or argument: 'IndexOf'

The third statement

```vb
oList.IndexOf "foo", 0, 1
```

contains one more argument then the expected signature so instead of not finding a match it finds one but reports;

> Wrong number of arguments or property assignment was not valid: 'IndexOf'

as the number of arguments exceeds what is expected by the method signature `IndexOf(arg, arg)`.

---

#### Useful Links

- [CA1402: Avoid overloads in COM visible interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182197.aspx) *(thanks to [@Pikoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579895/pikoh) for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001439/which-method-overload-will-be-accessible-from-vbscript#comment61556053_37001439))*
- [Determining .Net method suffix number in VBScript (COM-interop)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650296/692942)
- [Overloads in COM interop (CCW) - IDispatch names include suffix (_2, _3, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280960/692942)
- [Is there a tool for exploring/testing COM objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940498/692942)

Answer (score 3):

The overloads have numbered aliases:

```
>> Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
>> al.Add "poo"
>> al.Add "foo"
>> WScript.Echo al.IndexOf("poo", 0)
>>
0
>> WScript.Echo al.IndexOf("poo", 1)
>>
-1
>> WScript.Echo al.IndexOf_1("foo")
>>
Error Number:       438
Error Description:  Object doesn't support this property or method
>> WScript.Echo al.IndexOf_2("foo")
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
>> WScript.Echo al.IndexOf_3("foo")
>>
1
>>
```

I use trial and error to figure it out; there may be docs or introspection tools for a more scientific approach.

Comment: Indexes start from `_2` the first overload is always the original name there is no `_1`.